# Appcelerator Titanium Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',{}); not triggering when turn off the gps

Tags: gps, titanium, appcelerator

Whenever I turn on or turn off the **gps** in mobile device, I need to change an icon color. Currently i am using `Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',{});` for triggering when I turn on or off the gps. It is triggering when i on the gps,  but it is not triggering when I turn off the gps. I need this functionality in both **android** and **iOS**, it's not working in both.

Why this api is not triggering when we off the gps? Any other way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think theirs no such event-listener that can trigger when GPS turned off, instead you could try the below code and see if it solves your purpose :

```
exports.testGPS = function(_callback) {
    Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Recieve User Location";
    Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
     if (_callback && typeof(_callback)==='function') {
        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
                _callback ((e.error) ? false: true);
        });    
    }
}
```

> You can update this function according to your requirement. It will
>   through false when it gets and error while retriving the current
>   position of the device and hence we could conclude that the GPS
>   settings are turned off.

**Good Luck, 
Cheers**

## EDIT

You can do this by using the broadcast receiver, see below :

> Change the manifest in tiapp.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

> Create a broadcast receiver and Register it in index.js

```
var bc = Ti.Android.createBroadcastReceiver({
    onReceived: function() {
        Ti.API.info('Handling broadcast.');
    }
});

Ti.Android.registerBroadcastReceiver(bc, [Ti.Android.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED]);
```

Comment: For using this function i need to call this function right? But my issue is when i turn off the gps , i need a trigger. How to get that trigger everytime when i turn on or off the gps. Inside that function i can call the above mentioned function. Do u have any idea for this?

Comment: @Dev786: Hi, I have edited the questions, I think this will me your requirement. Have a look and let me know if it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working in android.Do we need to add any user permission inside manifest.Could you pls confirm this.Also i need to work this in ios also.

Comment: please provide the user permission to be mention in tiapp.xml

Comment: The braodcast receiver for location provider is not working.Could you please confirm it

Comment: Please reply to this if anyone has answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you listen location changer 
    `Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',function(response){});`
you have an event when the position change and when the gps set on or off

when you turn off you gps you have this response  is

on Android :

```
 {
  "type": "location",
  "source": {
    "bubbleParent": true,
    "hasCompass": true,
    "__propertiesDefined__": true,
    "preferredProvider": "gps",
    "Android": {
      "bubbleParent": true,
      "manualMode": false,
      "apiName": "Ti.Geolocation.Android"
    },
    "lastGeolocation": "{\"latitude\":36.4880079,\"longitude\":2.8170365,\"altitude\":0,\"accuracy\":42.5,\"heading\":0,\"speed\":0,\"timestamp\":1488278209059}",
    "_events": {
      "location": {}
    },
    "locationServicesEnabled": false,
    "accuracy": 1,
    "apiName": "Ti.Geolocation"
  },
  "bubbles": false,
  "success": true,
  "code": 0,
  "error": "network is disabled",
  "cancelBubble": false
}
```

on iOS

```
{
  "bubbles": true,
  "type": "location",
  "source": {
    "preferredProvider": null
  },
  "success": false,
  "code": 1,
  "error": "location",
  "cancelBubble": false
}
```

The event on iOS is fired when app is resumed, in my case I track GPS when app is on background, add this in the tiapp.xml

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
     <string>location</string>
</array>
```

you can find gps status 
for android in `response.source.locationServicesEnabled`
and on iOS check status or permission it if `response.error`

```
if(response.error){
   if(!Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled){
      //GPS desactivate
   }else if(Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS) || Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE)){
      //no authorised
  }
}
```

---

If you want to force change icon color even if you don't have the location event, check the GPS status and autorisation in onFocus event of the window it's contain the icon

Comment: Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',function(response){});  event itself is not triggering when we turn off the gps. Could you pls check whether this event is triggering or not when we turn off gps

Comment: I recheck, and complete my response. the event is triggered

Comment: You might want to use the manual mode on android (e.g. https://github.com/m1ga/titanium-libraries/blob/master/geo.js#L34) and set a minAge. If I remember correctly when you have a cached value when switching on the GPS it won't call the `location` event until your location is changed.

Comment: This event is calling perfectly when i on the gps , but not working when i off the gps.

Comment: What platform are you testing and TiSDK are you use, I have this response with TiSDK 5.5.1

Comment: i am testing in both android and ios...and TiSDK is 5.5.1 only

Comment: for me it's work on both platform, and you can see the callback for each platform, another solution you can force the check GPS status on focus window I update my post

Comment: now i am checking gps status when the window is in focus and it is working fine.When the app is going to background and coming back to foreground it is working fine becoz now we are checking it in window focus...but the problem now is  the app is not going to background..but i changing the gps status usiung dropdown in the header..at that time when i check with focus it is not working..focus event will not work in this case..any other listener for that

Comment: Yes windows its not blured on Android when dropdown the header, but on iOS if you want to change GPS status you need go to the params, 
I recheck know and I have the callback on off the GPS, there is probably a mistake in your code.

Comment: Can you please tell me which event will trigger when we move the dropdown in the header in android